# Rails 3 accepts_nested_attributes_for appears to be generating "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following two models:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Stocks
  belongs_to :trade_set
  attr_accessible :symbol, :percent, :shares, :open, :close, :trade_set_id, :name

  def set_stock_info(symbol, name)
    self.name = name
    self.symbol = symbol
  end

  def set_position_values(percent, shares, open, close)
    self.percent  = percent
    self.shares  = shares
    self.open  = open
    self.close  = close
  end
```

and

```
class Trade_Set < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :positions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :trading_period
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :workflow_state, :cash, :open, :close, :title,
                  :description, :log, :positions_attributes, :trading_period_id
  #...
end
```

My schema for the Positions model is:

```
create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "symbol"
    t.integer  "percent"
    t.integer  "shares"
    t.decimal  "open"
    t.decimal  "close"
    t.integer  "trade_set_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

If I "post" (update) a Trade_Set record with three Position records I get the following warning in the log:

```
  Position Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE ("positions".trade_set_id = 7)
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at, updated_at
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at, updated_at
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at, updated_at
```

Am I somehow not using accepts_nested_attributes_for correctly?  I'm not trying to make any changes to `created_at` or `updated_at` anywhere in my code.

Comment: Shouldn't attr_accessible :positions_attributes be attr_accessible :position_attributes?

Comment: @Waseem, it would be singular if OP had used `has_one` but a `has_many` would need the plural `:positions_attributes`

Comment: Thinking outside the box: Maybe the columns created by `t.timestamps` as opposed to specifying `t.datetime "created_at"` yourself are slightly different (in database properties :) and that Rails is using that fact to determine that those columns are not "magic". What happens if you use `t.timestamps` instead? Maybe try putting a breakpoint/log-statements to determine exactly when those warnings are being generated? Maybe one of the other column names such as open, close, symbol etc are screwing Rails up? Maybe some part of your code is in fact updating those fields and you don't know it yet?

Comment: Zabba: You are right my friend.

Comment: And just curious, why are you using strings to define the column names (e.g. `t.integer  "shares"`) instead of using symbols (the "common" Rails way - `t.integer  :shares`) ? I wonder if using strings instead of symbols has some impact on the "magic" columns of `created_at` and `updated_at`. Should not IMO, but worth a shot to look into that as well. As a note, you could also replace `t.integer  "trade_set_id"` with `t.references :trade_set` in the migration.

Comment: Zabba - I used the rails generate command and the rake db:migrate command to create all my models, controllers, views and migrations.  The schema file is unmodified from what was created as a result of these commands.  I've made no edits.  It appears the column names being "strings" instead of "symbols" is a choice made by the authors of these tools - unless I somehow screwed up using them.  I tried to follow the examples in the Rails Guides faithfully. [Yes, I'm very green at using rails...  :-)  ]  Thanks for the suggestion on t.timestamps, I'll look into that.